# Is it possible to disable default behaviour of input type email validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using redux-form validation and i am little bit confusing when my input catch me an error that the value is not correct(I mean default behaviour of browser). So i would like to disable this kind of default maintenance. Is there such function that blocks it?

Comment: don't use an type="email"? what is invalid that you want to ignore?

Comment: ok may be this is one the solution but I'm curious

Comment: Again: What are you trying to ignore that is being caught as invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `formnovalidate` attribute on the element.

Example:

```
<input type="email" name="userid" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">
```

Source:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formnovalidate.asp

Comment: Only adding "novalidate" attribute to form node helped me.